# Why poetry could not understand the kind of my os (Linux) and my cpu architecture?

Tags: python, artifactory, pypi, python-poetry

I'm working on a straightforward project where I employ 'poetry' for Python project management. For network isolation, I use Jfrog as my PyPi repository. In the pyproject.toml file, I've included certain dependencies, such as numpy. However, I noticed an issue: when I run the `poetry update` command, Poetry requests the macOS package from Jfrog and it want to download wheel file for `numpy-1.25.0-cp310-cp310-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl` package, even though my OS is Ubuntu 20.04. Additionally, there was another instance where Poetry requested to download `grpcio_tools-1.46.3-cp310-cp310-linux_armv7l.whl` the armv7l architecture wheel file from Jfrog, even though my operating system architecture is x86_64.
My pyproject.toml is:

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "demo_poetry"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = ["Your Name <you@example.com>"]
readme = "README.md"

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.8"
assertpy = "1.1"
asttokens = "2.0.1"
bcrypt = "3.2.0"
cached-property = "1.5.2"
certifi = "2021.10.8"
cffi = "1.14.3"
charset-normalizer = "2.0.8"
click = "8.0.3"
colorama = "0.4.4"
coloredlogs = "15.0.1"
cryptography = "3.4.8"
docopt = "0.6.2"
EditorConfig = "0.12.3"
func-timeout = "4.3.5"
grpcio = "1.46.3"
grpcio-tools = "1.46.3"
humanfriendly = "9.1"
idna = "3.3"
importlib-metadata = "3.1.1"
itsdangerous = "2.0.1"
Jinja2 = "3.0.1"
jsbeautifier = "1.14.0"
markdown2 = "2.4.3"
MarkupSafe = "2.0.0"
mccabe = "0.6.0"
paramiko = "2.11.0"
pptree = "3.1"
prompt-toolkit = "3.0.20"
protobuf = "3.19.3"
pycparser = "2.21"
Pygments = "2.12.0"
PyNaCl = "1.5.0"
pyvim = "3.0.2"
pyvmomi = "7.0.2"
requests = "2.26.0"
scp = "0.13.2"
six = "1.16.0"
toml = "0.10.2"
urllib3 = "1.26.7"
varname = "0.8.3"
wcwidth = "0.2.5"
Werkzeug = "2.0.1"
wrapt = "1.12.1"
zipp = "3.4.0"
protoc-gen-validate = "0.4.2"
boto3 = "1.24.72"
pysmb = "1.2.6"
tqdm = "4.62.3"
python-slugify = "5.0.0"
ImageHash = "4.3.1"
pythonping = "1.1.4"
flask = "2.0.2"
behave = "1.2.6"
behave-html-pretty-formatter = "1.9.1"

[[tool.poetry.source]]
name = "jfrog"
url = "https://jfrog.example.co/artifactory/api/pypi/all-pypi/simple/"
priority = "default"

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

Why poetry could not understand the kind of my os (Linux) and my cpu architecture to download spicific package?